# get ul li text list using htmlagilitypack

Tags: c#

Check the code bellow. Here i am trying to get list of all `li` text list from html bellow using htmlagilitypack library. but bellow i already trying to grab it using `span style` its not working. Whats wrong i am doing here?

C# Html htmlagilitypack:

```
HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(htmlinput);
var li_List = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@style='font-size: 14pt; line-height: 115%; font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; color: #ff0000;']/br/br/ul").ToList();
```

Html:

```
<div class="desc-title">PRODUCT DESCRIPTION</div>
<div class="desc-box">
<div class="desc-text">
<p><strong><span style="font-size: 14pt; line-height: 115%; font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; color: #ff0000;">Limited Stock Do Not Waste Time Place Your Order Now Before We Are Sold Out Again!<br /><br /></span></strong></p>
Hermitshell Hard EVA Travel Case Fits Sony SRF-M37W Walkman Digital Tuning Weather/FM/AM Stereo Radio<br /><br />
<ul>
 <li> Hermitshell Hard Travel Storage Carrying Case Bag </li> <li> Protect your favorite device from bumps dents and scratches </li> <li> Made to fit Sony SRF-M37W Walkman Digital Tuning Weather/FM/AM Stereo Radio </li> <li> Material:EVA ,Color: Black; Internal size: 3.7 x 2.7 x 1.4 inch </li> <li> For sale is case only (device and accessories are sold separately) </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It works. It found `span` nodes.

Comment: my bad..edited question plz check `/br/br/ul` added. i need `li` elements only

Comment: Did you try `htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//ul/li");` ?

Comment: you mean `htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//ul/li").ToList()` this? this selects others nodes from whole html. I need to select `span style='.....'` then go next ul only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply go back one step and try to grab that node `<div class="desc-text">`. I have tried with this like bellow and able to grab `li` elements as you wanted if i am not wrong.

```
var li_List = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='desc-text']/ul/li").ToList();
```